# how to display ajax server response data into datatable using php

Tags: php, datatable

after initialize data-table in my page its working fine, but i need to display server response data dynamically in data-table.  I can receive data in console.log(data)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'xxxxxx/xxxxxxx',
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#datatable').dataTable({
                    data: data,
                    serverside:true,
                    columns: [
                        { 'data': 'UserId' },
                        { 'data': 'UserDepartment' },
                        { 'data': 'UserCourse' },
                        { 'data': 'UserName' },
                        { 'data': 'UserBirthDate' },
                        { 'data': 'UserEmail' },
                        { 'data': 'UserContact' }
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT  FROM user";
            $sql_result = $conn->query($sql);

            $response = array('data' => $sql_result );
            echo json_encode($response);

    ?>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'xxxxxx/xxxxxxx',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#datatable').dataTable({
                    data: data,
                    serverside: true,
                    columns: [{
                        'data': 'UserId'
                    }, {
                        'data': 'UserDepartment'
                    }, {
                        'data': 'UserCourse'
                    }, {
                        'data': 'UserName'
                    }, {
                        'data': 'UserBirthDate'
                    }, {
                        'data': 'UserEmail'
                    }, {
                        'data': 'UserContact'
                    }]
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: if this not work then try this  echo json_encode($sql_result );.....waiting for your response

Comment: i am getting error like, Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

Comment: just echo jsencode in php file.....make sure you have not echo anything or it error cause url wrong...you can check it by view pagesource...please copy  my edited code again

Comment: i think its doesn't send the post data,  i am getting Message: Undefined index: data,Filename: controllers/product_controller.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you have things out of order you could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
    $('#DataTable tfoot th').each(function ()
    {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
    });

    var table = $('#DataTable').DataTable({
        "select": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "./ServerSide.php",
            "type": "POST"
        }
    });
});
```

I'm pretty sure you don't even have to list the column names, they'll be picked up in your file passed to the `url`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML CODE

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" id="datatables">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Mobile</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        
                    </tbody>
                </table>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $('#datatables').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax":{
                    "url": "fetch.php",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "type": "POST"
                    },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "id"},
                    { "data": "name"},
                    { "data": "email"},
                    { "data": "mobile"},
                    { "data": "manage"}
                ],
                "columnDefs": [ {
                    "targets": [0,4],
                    "orderable": false
                } ],
                "order": [[ 1, "ASC"]],
            });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#dataTables').DataTable();
        } );
    });
    </script>
```

PHP CODE

```
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbName")
        
        $req = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM register where delete_status = 0");
    
        $s = (isset($_POST['search']['value'])) ? $_POST['search']['value'] : '';
        
        if(!empty($s))
        {
            $req = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM register WHERE name LIKE '%$s%' ");
        }
        
        $totalData = mysqli_num_rows($req);
        $totalFiltered = mysqli_num_fields($req);
    
        $data = array();
        if(!empty($req))
        {
            foreach ($req as $key=>$value)
            {
                $edit = "";
                $delete = "";
    
                $nestedData['id'] = $key+1;
                $nestedData['name'] = $value['name'];
                $nestedData['email'] = $value['email'];
                $nestedData['mobile'] = $value['mobile'];
                
                $nestedData['manage'] = "<a href='$edit' class='btn  btn-warning  btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Edit</a> &nbsp;&nbsp; <a onclick='return delet()' href='$delete' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs confirm-delete' ><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</a>";
    
                $data[] = $nestedData;
    
            }
        }
        
        $json_data = array(
            "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalData),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
            "data"            => $data
        );
        echo json_encode($json_data);
```

include jquery file

```
   jquery.min.js
   bootstrap.min.js
   jquery.dataTables.min.js
   dataTables.buttons.min.js
   dataTables.bootstrap.min.js
```